# Can not install django via Ubuntu bash on windows

Tags: django, pip

happy holidays to you :)

I can not install the Django package by the python pip package manager.
The installation returns an error that you can see below on the image

If you want more pictures to help me, let me know

[Windows 10 - Ubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV2vM.png)

Thank you, simply

Comment: No, we want *fewer* pictures. Copy-paste the error message into the question **as text**.

Comment: @@JJ Okey, sorry JJJ

Answer (score 0):

The latest django version does not support python 2.7 try this

```
pip install django==1.11
```

Comment: That will get the initial 1.11 release, which won't have the most up to date security patches and bugfixes. Instead you should use `django<2.0` to get the latest version before 2.0.